# Simpler way to write overloaded operators +/-

Tags: c#

can someone tell me if there's a simpler way to write this (the static sequencing operators) piece of code. I'm trying to make it simpler so I can explain it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Sequencing
    {
        public long Bits { get; set; }

        public Sequencing() { }

        public Sequencing (long Bits)
        {
            this.Bits = Bits;
        }

        public static Sequencing operator +(Sequencing a, Sequencing b) => 
              new Sequencing(a.Bits | b.Bits);

        public static Sequencing operator -(Sequencing a, Sequencing b) => 
              new Sequencing(a.Bits & b.Bits);


        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Bits.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Describe which part you don't comprehend. It's simple [operator overriding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading).

Comment: The static sequencing operators

Comment: It's operator overriding. Check msdn: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading

Comment: How can I rewrite it? to make it even simpler

Comment: It's almost the simplest way to override an operator. It let you could do something like a+b.

Comment: There is really no way to answer the question in its current form. There is no way for us to know what changes you are looking for based on "make it simpler so *I can explain it*.". As @LouisGo said this is pretty much the simplest and most compact way to write the code shown. Probably the best approach for you at this point would be to just write that class yourself so you'd use only constructs you know...

Comment: You may see a way  NOT using lambda expression [Here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCAMACEEAsBuWDkQHQBkBLAOwEdM4kVcAVAUwA8AXC7FAVgtmIEMBbOgGcADjwDGdRAGEA9sUEyANnQCCw4dBgBvWIj3IAzMjCIAynVIBXOsTEkA5rv06Y+t4cSK59xACFCTIKIWoj2dCyIguHoiAC+sE7uHuZWNnbE9gAUAJTBcQmuSckW1rYOiJleGX4BgtmJ7i5F7kwAFoSCuP6BiAC8NYEUzfEwDW4gRigAbGYlaeUywnQATjxMMsuIANSZKaXpPjwANLOpZdUARrm9AHyIY82IxHQA7qf7Dpk8XbWIwIgXH6BbJcQpJCY4GZ7ebVRYrNYbRAAWl2c3OhxO0PRAOudwezWebyxBy+QKCADIAWSQQV8R4ZAA3FbLQgAE0kKCQNBkpiYLIyOTpTUeehAAHYBp1ubz+VkaWD3CM3CNYkA)

Comment: @LouisGo but you've already gave them link that shows both variants of implementing the operator... I don't think that decompiled code would help any more than MSDN... Probably they need some other way altogether - maybe not even operators? (post would benefit from [edit] to bring some clarify)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I agree, but in case op doesn't know how to read lambda. That's all I can do.

Comment: Thank you guys for the help. I just didn't want to use operator overloading because we're not at that level yet in the course I'm taking. It works but I gotta find a way to use material the teacher has already covered. I found something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can avoid using operators:

```
public class BitsSequence 
{
    public long Bits {get;}
    public BitsSequence(long bits = 0) => Bits = bits;

    public BitsSequence Union(BitsSequence other) => new BitsSequence(Bits | other.Bits);
    public BitsSequence Intersection(BitsSequence other) => new BitsSequence(Bits & other.Bits);

    public override string ToString() => Bits.ToString();
}
```